Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 15359 with tensorflow lite model
I'm trying to build an android app using following tensorflow lite model:
https://www.kaggle.com/models/spsayakpaul/mirnet/tfLite/fixed-dr/1?tfhub-redirect=true
it is an image conversion model for low light image restoration.
Problem is I'm getting an error:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 15359 with tensorflow lite model
probably located in the postprocessing method
here is my code:
public class MIRNetConverter {

    private static final int IMAGE_SIZE = 256;
    private static final int MODEL_INPUT_SIZE = 400;

    public static Bitmap convertToNormal(Context context, Bitmap lowLightImage) {
        Bitmap normalImage = null;
        try {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = preprocess(lowLightImage);
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3 * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * 4);
            Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(context), new     Interpreter.Options());
            interpreter.run(inputBuffer, outputBuffer);
            normalImage = postprocess(outputBuffer);
            interpreter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MIRNetConverter", "Error processing image: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return normalImage;
    }

    private static MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("mirnet_dr.tflite");
        File modelFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "mirnet_dr.tflite");
        copyFile(inputStream, modelFile);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(modelFile);
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileChannel.position();
        long declaredLength = fileChannel.size();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    private static void copyFile(InputStream inputStream, File outputFile) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

    private static ByteBuffer preprocess(Bitmap image) {
        // Resize the input image to match the model's input shape (400x400)
        Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, MODEL_INPUT_SIZE, MODEL_INPUT_SIZE, true);

        // Allocate a ByteBuffer to hold the preprocessed input data
        int inputSize = 12; // Size of input tensor expected by the model
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(inputSize);
        inputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // Iterate over each pixel in the resized image
        // Note: In this example, we'll simply add placeholder values to the input buffer
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize / Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE; i++) {
            // Add placeholder values to the input buffer
            inputBuffer.putFloat(0.5f); // Example placeholder value
        }

        // Rewind the buffer to prepare for reading
        inputBuffer.rewind();

        return inputBuffer;
    }


    private static Bitmap postprocess(ByteBuffer outputBuffer) {
        Bitmap normalImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int[] pixels = new int[IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE];

        // Ensure proper buffer setup
        outputBuffer.rewind();
        outputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        outputBuffer.limit(outputBuffer.capacity());

        if (normalImage != null && normalImage.getWidth() == IMAGE_SIZE && normalImage.getHeight() == IMAGE_SIZE && pixels.length == IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE) {
            for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE; i++) {
                float r = outputBuffer.getFloat() * 255.0f;
                float g = outputBuffer.getFloat() * 255.0f;
                float b = outputBuffer.getFloat() * 255.0f;
                pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | (((int) r) << 16) | (((int) g) << 8) | (int) b;
            }
            normalImage.setPixels(pixels, 0, IMAGE_SIZE, 0, 0, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE);
        } else {
            Log.e("MIRNetConverter", "Error: Normal image bitmap is not properly allocated or pixels array size is incorrect");
        }

        return normalImage;
    }
}

I've been trying to solve this issue in any way possible but it's hard to even understand what causes it
